Stop Excel from copying blank cells and making them zero
Consider the Excel worksheet where A1 is blank, and A2, B1, B2 have the indicated formulas:

The values of these cells are:

Excel does not put a blank in B1, it places a 0.  That has caused me problems.  I know there are workarounds for this (see, for example Stop treating blanks as zeros).
Why does Excel put in a zero in this simple situation?  Is there an option in Excel that will fix this?  [Note:  The option to display zero as blank does not fix this].  Or do I always have to do a workaround that involves testing if the original cell is blank or has zero length and then putting in an empty string?

Use the "workaround." _"It is not a workaround to test if a cell is blank, it is necessary depending on the functions you are employing."... from the accepted answer in the linked thread.

You need to learn how to live with it. :-)

You can conceal the 0, but the cell will not be blank, because it contains a formula.

The comments above confirm my suspicion that I just need to deal with it.  The real question is why does Excel have such a horrible feature?  If column A has a bunch of numbers and blanks, and Column B is just a formula copy of A (each cell in B looks like =An where n is the row number), the average of Column B would be different.  It is so easy to make a mistake that way.

Every calculation should be based on some initial statements and assumptions. Evidently the blank cell is defined as the cell contains nothing: neither formula nor constant.
Explanation of behavior when zero is returned by the reference to the blank cell is very simple: a cell containing a formula is not blank, thus the formula should return a value. And, considering that Excel tries to treat a value as the number first, as the date second, and as the text finally, the empty cell is treated as zero.
COUNTBLANK function (look at the Remark section) provides the special behavior to count the cell with the empty text as the blank cell.
Other functions (DCOUNTA, TOROW, TOCOL etc.) do not treat the empty text as the blank cell.


Thank you.  That makes sense.  I appreciate the time you took to respond.
